# Disk quota exceeded - can't run "rhc app-tidy"

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

My application's database is too large and it's exceeding my disk space:

```
rhc show-app reader --gears quota
Gear                     Cartridges                      Used Limit
------------------------ ------------------------------- ---- -----
5160647d4382ec2da5000019 php-5.3 postgresql-8.4 cron-1.4 1 GB  1 GB

quota -s
Disk quotas for user 5160647d4382ec2da5000019 (uid 1825): 
 Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
/dev/mapper/EBSStore01-user_home01
              1013M       0   1024M            7640       0   80000
```

But, when I run "rhc app-tidy" I get this:

```
rhc app-tidy reader
Warning: Gear 5160647d4382ec2da5000019 is using 98.9% of disk quota
Failed to execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/5160647d4382ec2da5000019/postgresql
```

Can you temporarily increase my quota, so I can run the tidy command? My application URL is https://reader-rodrigocarvalho.rhcloud.com/

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Try sshing into your app and delete the log files and  anything else that might be unneeded manually.

Comment: I've already tried that... The database is what is taking all the space:

    du -hsx * | sort -rh | head -10
    941M postgresql
    25M app-root
    20M app-deployments
    15M php
    5.0M git
    108K cron
    0 postgresql-8.4
    0 php-5.3
    0 cron-1.4

I'm running TT-RSS, my issue is this: https://github.com/disconn3ct/tiny_tiny_rss-openshift-quickstart/issues/5

Comment: I found a log folder and now I was able to run the command! Thanks!